# Javascript Regex not working on script but working on console

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate only 4 numbers like this:

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/XpFgQO/1)

It is working on the above page, but when I use it on a script it is not working:

```
var reg = new RegExp('^\d{4}$/');
reg.test(1234);
reg.test('1234');
```

Both are returning false...

If I test on the browser console like this:

```
/^\d{4}$/.test('1234');
/^\d{4}$/.test(1234);
```

Both are returning true.

What I'm missing?

Comment: You could simply use `/^\d{4}$/.test(1234)` directly in your code ?

Comment: And if you still need the variable you should initialize it like this `var reg = RegExp(/^\d{4}$/)`

Comment: looks like you're missing a single slash `'^\d{4}$/'` should be `'/^\d{4}$/'`

Comment: You're using different code in your script vs. the console. That's why you're getting different results.

Comment: @Nicolas, yes this way is working, but I need the regex on a variable. Thanks!

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak - close . . . you don't use the opening and closing slashes in a string parameter for the `RegExp` constructor.  Also the `\d` needs to have its slash escaped in a `RegExp` string parameter (i.e., `\\d`).  Basically, Chin Leung nailed it in his answer below.   :)

Comment: @Albeis use it like that `var regex = /^\d{4}$/` and then `regex.test(1234)`

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas! is working as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is because your `RegExp` is not initialized properly.

You can either do:

```
// Note the \\ to escape the backslash
var reg = new RegExp('^\\d{4}$');
```

Or

```
var reg = new RegExp(/^\d{4}$/);
```

Comment: this helped me, can't reuse it each time apparently